# wp_generate_attachment_metadata returns empty array

Tags: uploads, media

```
        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
            $uploadedImage = wp_handle_upload($_FILES[$key], $upload_overrides);

            pre_r($uploadedImage);

            if (!isset($uploadedImage['error'])) {

                $attachID = wp_insert_attachment($uploadedImage, $uploadedImage['file']);

                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachID, $uploadedImage['file'] );

                print_r($attach_data);

                wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachID, $attach_data );

            } else {

            }
        }
```

Im almost positive this code should work. I have looked around and people were saying once the added the require_once this worked.

The upload works, the file is added to the media library but no metadata is generated.

Any suggestions?

Comment: wp_insert_attachment takes as the first parameter an array with attachment data. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following is happening here:

1. As @Luke [pointed out](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91951/wp-generate-attachment-metadata-returns-empty-array#comment130517_91951), `wp_insert_attachment()` takes an array of post data. The format of the array you are passing to it is not correct. The keys are different. What should be stored as the `post_mime_type`, is being passed with the key `type`. Because of this, no mime type is being saved for the post.
2. `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` is [looking for the mime type](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L77) so it can generate the metadata based on that. But since the mime type wasn't saved correctly it just returns an empty array.

The solution is to do `$uploadedImage['post_mime_type'] = $uploadedImage['type']`, or better yet use [`media_handle_upload()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload), which will handle the whole media upload for you.

Example based on your code:

```
foreach ( $_FILES as $key => $file ) {
    media_handle_upload( $key, 0, array(), $upload_overrides );
}
```